# Função ajax/js não funciona

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Segue abaixo meu código, com a função e o campo. Ao testar não resulta nada, não sei o que está errado. Fiz esta função para verificar se tal período já existe no banco. Mas não sei nem como verificar se o arquivo php ta recebendo os dados ou se o resultado está voltando e não estou exibindo corretamente.

Desde já agradeço as sugestões.

```
function verifica(){                  
      var id  = document.getElementsByName("id")[0].value;
      var dt1 = document.getElementsByName("datahora_inicial")[0].value;
      var dt2 = document.getElementsByName("date")[0].value;
      var parametros = {
              method: "GET"
      };
      fetch("php/verifica.php?id=" + id + "&dt1=" + dt1 + "&dt2=" + dt2, parametros).then(function(resposta) {
          return resposta.json();
      }).then(function(retorno){
          console.log(retorno)
          if (retorno == 1) {
            document.getElementById("resultado").value = "Período indisponível! Altere-o.";
            document.getElementById("resultado").style.display = 'inline-block';
            document.getElementById("link").style.display = 'inline-block';
          }else{
            document.getElementById("resultado").style.display = 'none';
          }
      });
  }




<label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Fim</label>
<div class="col-md-5">
  <input type="text" class="form-control round-input" name="date" required="required" id="dtfim" onchange="verifica();" value="" disabled="disabled">
   <input type="text" class="form-control round-input" id="resultado" disabled="disabled" style="display: none; width: 60px;"><a style="display: none;" href='link.php' id="link">Link</a>                                                            
</div>
```

php:

```
header('Content-Type: json/application'); 
$id  = $_GET['id'];
$dt1 = $_GET['dt1'];
$dt1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dt1));

$dt2 = $_GET['dt2'];
$dt2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dt2));

$select    = "SELECT * FROM lista WHERE id = '$id' and start <= '$dt1' and end >= '$dt2'";
$result    = mysqli_query($conexao, $select);

if ((mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)){
    $mostrar = 1;
    echo json_encode($mostrar); 
}else{
    $mostrar = 2;
    echo json_encode($mostrar);
}
```

Comment: O que aparece no console ? A requisição funciona corretamente ?

Comment: Não existe um elemento chamado `id` no DOM. Não existe um elemento chamado `datahora_inicial` no DOM. Qual é o código do arquivo `php/verifica.php`? Se no primeiro `then` você retorna `resposta.json()`, tem certeza que no segundo o valor esperado para `retorno` é 1? Reforço o questionamento do Otto: aparece algo no console? A requisição é feita?

Comment: Na primeira vez que fiz sim, retornava 1 ou 2, mas agora nada.

Comment: E você alterou o que no projeto?

Comment: O local no qual estou chamando a função está correto?

Comment: O campo de data final agora não é mais digitável, ele apenas recebe um resultado. Talvez algo neste quesito esteja atrapalhando no momento de pegar o value dele. E não sei como verificar se a requisição retornou algum registro.